# CPU 100% usage caused by unknown postgres query

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I installed `timescaledb` extension (v.5.0) for PostgreSQL (v9.6) on 16.04 Linux box and observes that Postgres process occupies 100% CPU:

here is result of `top` command:

```
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM   TIME+   COMMAND
19885 postgres  20   0  192684   3916   1420 S 98.3  0.1   5689:04 x3606027128
```

I run query `SELECT pid, datname, usename, query FROM pg_stat_activity` and find two weird queries

```
pid   datname   username  query
19882 postgres  postgres  select Fun013301 ('./x3606027128 &')
19901 postgres  postgres  select Fun013301 ('./ps3597605779 &')
```

function `Fun013301` is not existed in postgres database. I cannot figure out what `./x3606027128` command is!?

Comment: I think your question will get more attention at https://dba.stackexchange.com ;).

Comment: You should open an issue - but I see you did that already.

Comment: It could be a malware that somehow crept into your postgres install, given how it hides itself under generated names and executes CPU-eating programs in background. I would check the sources from which you installed anything recently, not just timescaledb.

Comment: Under linux you may also use `gcore` on the PID to capture a live core dump of the program for further analysis, and `strace` to capture its system calls.

Comment: Looks like an SQL injection was used to save a malware file `x3606027128`, created a function `Fun013301` that runs a command from argument using a shell and a run of this function that starts the malware. I'd suspect an attack on the application that uses the database cluster. You probably connect to the database using a superuser account (`postgres`), which is a very bad practice and makes such attacks easier - you should've created a special user account and the dedicated database for this account.

Comment: from the fact it did not create a not superuser account and fun13301 with `SECURITY DEFINER` to hide itself I assume it can be very primityve - so rejecting connections to postgres database to postgres user can make it stop self initiating - try creating another SU and forbidding postgres to connect (of course previously pg_backend_terminating runnign pids19882 and 19901)

Comment: [You have been hacked](https://www.imperva.com/blog/deep-dive-database-attacks-scarlett-johanssons-picture-used-for-crypto-mining-on-postgre-database/)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. It was due to - some transactions was getting stuck and running for long time. Thus, CPU utilization was at 100% all the time. Following command helped to find out the connections running for the longest time:

```
SELECT max(now() - xact_start) FROM pg_stat_activity
                           WHERE state IN ('idle in transaction', 'active');
```

This command shows the time since when a connection is running. This time should not be greater than an hour. So killing the connection which was running from long time or stuck at any point, worked for me. I followed [this post](https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/10/debug-postgresql-performance-issues.html) for monitoring and solving my issue. [Post](https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/10/debug-postgresql-performance-issues.html) includes lots of useful commands to monitor this situation.