# Postgres uses High CPU - unable to find

Tags: postgresql, cpu, utilization

I'm having Postgres 9.6.4 in Ubuntu 17.  After every few hours (say 6 hours or so), the OS CPU utilization becomes very high (upto 98% or more).
I did the following:

```
# ps aux | grep postgres
```

Whenever the process/CPU is high, the above command shows postgres processes like this:

```
31928     1 ./x3665600000                0.2 99.8
```

The process name with x3665600000 always consumes near to 100% CPU.

When I checked the pg_stat_activity table, it shows SQL query like this:

```
select Fun310280 ('./x3665600000 &')
select Fun310280 ('./ps3657178651 &')
```

What is this function causing Postgres to use very high CPU?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46617329/905902

Comment: Probably something like this: https://www.imperva.com/blog/2018/03/deep-dive-database-attacks-scarlett-johanssons-picture-used-for-crypto-mining-on-postgre-database/